# How can I use Content Scripts and Message Passing to gather metadata from a website and send it back to my Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, metadata, message-passing, content-script

I am creating a Chrome Extension and am very confused on how content scripts and message passing works. Below I detail the goals of my extension and the code I have so far.

**The extension needs to:**

1. Be active for all webpages
2. Gather the metadata (specifically keywords) from each site the user is on
3. Communicate the metadata back to the extension in a way that the extension can analyze the keywords and act accordingly. *The extension will display different text depending on the category of the site (i.e. social media, blog, sports site)]*

I have not included the code for popup.html, as I can get normal text to popup when you click the icon of my extension.

**My files so far:**

---

**manifest.json**

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "my extension",
"description": "This is my first chrome extension.",
"version": "1.0",

"content_scripts": [ {"matches": ["<all_urls>"], "run_at": "document_end", "js["testscript.js"] }],

"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "background"],

"background": "background.html",

"browser_action": { "default_icon": "my_logo.png", "default_popup": "popup.html" }
```

---

**contentscript.js**

```
var meta_keywords = getKeywords();

chrome.extension.sendRequest(meta_keywords);

function getKeywords() {
   data = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
   keywords = []; 
   var len = data.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     if (data[i].name == 'keywords') {
        keywords = data[i].content.split(",");
     }
   }
   return keywords;
}
```

---

**background.html**

```
//I really have no idea what this means or how to use it...
//I just know that I need some sort of onRequest function

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(keywords, sender, sendResponse) {})
```

---

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I have read numerous tutorials and Google's documentation, but I just am not getting it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What documentation did you use? The API format in your question was deprecated over 10 Chrome versions ago. To get up-to-date, read the documentation for [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) and use [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage)/[`onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage) instead of `chrome.extension.*`.

Answer (score 0):

few months ago i tried to create smth like singleton for devtools extension
it have messaging between background page content page and devtools page take a look

https://github.com/ruddog/chrome-devtools-skeleton/

hope it will be  helpful for you